# Is pymysql connection thread safe? Is pymysql cursor thread safe?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, thread-safety, pymysql

I have a queue data structure where multiple threads consume items, each thread is going to write to a database using PyMySQL, no other sync is needed among threads.

Is it race free to use the same cursor coming from the same pymysql connection in all threads?

Is it race free to use different cursor per thread coming from the same connection?

(of course to use multiple connections in multiple threads is ok, because in this case there is no shared resource, I have no interest in this case)

Comment: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/267

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to El Ruso, for point one direction

I found the answer in the pymysql source after understand the DBAPI2 has a specification indicating how to answer this question depending on the implementation. In case of PyMySQL it means it is not threadsafe for connections nor cursors.

[https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/**init**.py#L40](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/__init__.py#L40) Line

PyMySQL is threadsafe = 1 means: *Threads may share the module, but not connections.*

(Read the PEP-0249 specification http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety)