# A sentence is run multiple times, and different errors appear

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, ubuntu, pymysql

Run multiple times without modifying any line of code
`cursor.execute(sql2)`
1.AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
2.IndexError
index out of range
3.AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settimeout'
4.AssertionError
Protocol error, expecting EOF
5.OperationalError
(2014, 'Command Out of Sync')
6.InternalError
Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 2
7.OSError
[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
.......

```
def getPosition(connect,ID):                                                       
    lock = threading.Lock()
    
    sql2 = "SELECT district,region,community FROM Position WHERE ID = {0};".format(ID)
    lock.acquire()
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    connect.ping(reconnect=True)
    cursor.execute(sql2)                         #the setnece 
    
   
    ans = ""
    try:
        l = cursor.fetchone()
        ans = l[0]+l[1]+l[2]
    except Exception:
        return False
    finally:
        lock.release()
    return ans
```

I use the producer-consumer model to connect to the mysql database through pymysql

Comment: The lock you use protects nothing, you should create it once and pass to the workers in threads.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it's safe to share pymysql connections https://stackoverflow.com/a/47182792/4478375